# how to decode base64 string to NSString in ios?

Tags: iphone, base64, decode

I have received some data in base64string format from JSON pasring in iphone. Now i want that data to store or decode in String. I have user Base64 class. 
It return me null value. so pls help me!!!

Comment: Very straightforward question)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I hope it will helpful to you

```
NSString *decodeString = @"Raja";
```

Encode String

```
NSData *encodeData = [decodeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [encodeData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"Encode String Value: %@", base64String);
```

Decode String

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Decode String Value: %@", decodedString);
```

Comment: this code works well But in my case i get xml response from server which are already in base64 encoded .I have decode that data but when i use this method it returns null. can anybody suggest me tackle this problem ??

Comment: what is your xml response @amitgupta

Comment: this decoded code contain sHTML code CgoKPCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBIVE1MIDQuMCBUcmFuc2l0aW9uYWwvL0VOIj4KPCEtLSA8IURP
Q1RZUEUgSFRNTCBQVUJ......0bWw+Cg==

Comment: try with constant data same as in xml response through check it working ?

Comment: https://www.base64decode.org/ check with this url. your response code is decoded i had got html string. check with your xml response @amitgupta

Comment: when i decode  response  string  from [link](http://base64online.org/decode/)  then it returns a html table  i have to show this table on  UIWEBVIEW

Comment: i have to decode this response and show on UIwebView  but when i decode this it return nil

Comment: this above example works may be in string value. if your response have html tag and html language try any other framework

Comment: give me some idea to tackle this situation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71320/discussion-between-codercat-and-amit-gupta).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use like this..First you need to get this base64 library

https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64

And then import this file

```
   #import "NSData+Base64.h"

NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:baseString];

NSString *convertedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I hope it helps.